# Python - Accept list of strings (names) as parameter and store it in array

Tags: python, arrays, string, parameters

This is Python code.
I found multiple examples of storing integer values in an array variable but dont see any working example of storing strings (passed as parameter) stored in array.

```
try: 
    my_list = []
    while True:
        **my_list.append(int(input()))**
except: 
    print(my_list)
```

The above code gives output as below where i provided 4 integer input values.

```
./test-00.py 
3
54
7
90

[3, 54, 7, 90]
```

If i change the code to accepts strings instead of integers as shown in code line below the result breaks and i am thrown out as soon as i hit Return.

```
my_list.append(str(input()))
```

Can anyone tell me how i can take multiple strings as values of one array variable and print them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exiting your infinite loop in first code snippet because you encountered an exception. An enter pressed is equal to reading an empty string and empty string is not converted to integer. Hence exception is raised and you exit `while True` loop.

**Demo**:

```
>>> int(input())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here you can implement the same approach considering that you need to break from the loop on empty input:

```
my_list = []
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == '':
        break
    my_list.append(inp)
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird way to take input. You have no exit condition in your while loop. So your first example will keep running until you input a non-integer (or just press integer since an empty string when passed to `int()` will also throw an exception).

In your second example, since there are no invalid inputs (all string are acceptable to `str()`) - you just keep taking input forever.

So even in your second example, you are storing strings in the list - just that you have not left any option to **stop taking input from the user**

You need to give the user an exit condition (like entering `quit` or `exit`) or take a limited number of input.

see this example:

```
my_list = []
for _ in range(5):  # take only 5 inputs
    my_list.append(input()) # no need for `str`, `input` already returns a string

print(my_list)
```

Which results in:

```
1
a
b
4
hello

['1', 'a', 'b', '4', 'hello']  # strings in array, just what you want
```